# Unable to dequeue a cell with identifier "GroupMessageCell"

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have two tableViews displayed within a tab. For the first one that opens, there is no error, but upon selecting the second tab, the error appears:

```
2016-05-17 21:07:23.730 FeastApp[11007:172938] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.60.7/UITableView.m:6573
2016-05-17 21:07:23.736 FeastApp[11007:172938] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier GroupMessageCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

Even though I have set the row identifier as: `GroupMessageCell`:

[image]

within my nested TableView:

[image]

and class:

```
class GroupMessageList: UITableViewController {

    var getGroups: Firebase!
    var groups: [Group] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getGroupsWithMessages()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    // MARK: - Table View

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.groups.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("GroupMessageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let group: Group

        group = groups[indexPath.row]

        // Update the rows with the proper object
        cell.textLabel!.text = "\(group.groupName) \(group.groupID)"
        return cell
    }

    func getGroupsWithMessages() {

        getGroups = Firebase(url: Global.sharedInstance.firebaseMainURL + "usersGroups/" + Global.sharedInstance.userID)

        self.getGroups.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

            print(snapshot)

            for detailData in snapshot.children {

               // print(detailData.value)

               self.groups.append(Group(groupName: "test", groupID: detailData.key))

                print(self.groups.count)

            }

            self.tableView!.reloadData()

        })
    }        
}
```

How can I prevent this error from occurring?

Answer (score 2):

You have not set the class for **GroupMessageCell**

to do select storyboard and

[image]

and then

[image]

verify that Class **GroupMessageCell**

set identifier

[image]

Comment: There is no class `GroupMessageCell`, I have the exact same setup as my individual messages tab, but yes errors persist...

Answer (score 1):

Three Potentials Trouble Areas:

1. Ensure the cell identifier is present - [Looks fine based on your details]
2. Did you set the class of your TableViewController to GroupMessageList on the storyboard like so: [image: custom table view class]
3. Does the error still occur after you run Product > Clean.

Hope one of these helps!

Comment: Gremlins. Glad you got it sorted.